# How to use date and Time API in android development?

Tags: android, api

I am new to android programming so please help me

I want to access Time and date of a country and have that API too but dont know how to use it in my android Code can anyone help me please......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard Java DateFormat class.

For example to display the current date and time do the following:

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
System.out.println("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

You can initialise a Date object with your own values, however you should be aware that the constructors have been deprecated and you should really be using a Java Calendar object.

Comment: It autometically take ur device zone dude

Comment: format correctly according to the device configuration a date and time when having year, month, day, hour and minute